# When Blender says out of memory error what exactly do I need to free up or replace?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render this complex scene I am using an hdr and a couple of hair particle systems and when I tried to render the animation it said out of memory so what do I need to do ? Do I get a new bigger ram or a new graphics card . I’ve been using blender for about a year and it was rendering fine but now I am trying both cpu and gpu renders and it won’t work .

Comment: Optimize your scene, reduce complexity, subdivision levels, particle counts, texture sizes, number of objects, use instancing whenever possible. If that is insufficient then consider upgrading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you rendering it on GPU or CPU?
If it's GPU then you

(a) try splitting up and rendering the scene over different render layers

-OR-

(b) try rendering it on CPU instead. I had to render a complex scene too earlier this month, it kept crashing every time I tried to rendering it on GPU; worked just fine on CPU however it took longer (obviously). If the problem still persists on CPU rendering then you could consider upgrading your RAM; I, myself, have 16GB and that just barely enough for complex renders.

Comment: What does the frame rate effect ? Does it take up memory or what ? I rendered another scene with a lot of particles but no hdr at 24 FPS I want to try 60fps is that too extreme?

Comment: @RonyAhmed 60fps means you need to render 60 images to get one second of animation. And you should render as individual PNG or EXR images, not a single movie file.

Comment: @RonyAhmed yeah, what he said, rendering the output as an image sequence is a very safe method, in case the render does fail, you can continue from that point onwards... As for your other question, no, it doesn't affect the frame rate

Answer (score 1):

There is not **one**factor that determines the amount of nemeory use, but a multitude of them:
The amount of vertices/edges/faces, number of subdivisions, particles, texture size and bit depth, complexity of the shaders, volumetrics, simulations, ray bounces, samples, render size, post production effects, etc, etc

As you see the list is long. Optimize as much as you can.